# Native mySQL SQL Select with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a class "Panel" with which I have been working until now, provisionally and to move forward, with a simple query, from which I simply chose the first value:

```
result = self.database.session.query(Panel)
panel : Panel = result.first() #Loads and bind firs panel object.
```

At this point, I do need to properly select the values ​​from the database. The select in SQL language selects correctly and in the order that I need the elements of the panel. I know that a native select can be sent directly through SQLAlchemy, and it is something I have used for column values, but now I would need the "panel" object attached to the session and loaded automatically:

```
query = f"SELECT PANEL.* FROM PANEL LEFT JOIN PANEL_BOT_DONE ON PANEL.PANE_ID = PANEL_BOT_DONE.PANE_ID AND PANEL_BOT_DONE.BOT_ID = {self.id} ORDER BY PANE_BOT_USES ASC, PANE_GOODSCORE DESC"
result = self.database.executeQuery(query)
panel = result.first() #This line returns tuples. Any way to load automatically the panel value?
```

Is there a way to automatically load the Panel object with this select that has all the fields (and only the fields) from your table without needing to load column by column, and then bind to session?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I misunderstood your question or if you were confused about the ORM or maybe a little bit of both.  You can use the orm to generate SQL queries behind the scenes to get arbitrary results and stuff them into the objects automatically.  I wasn't able to fully understand your class relationships so I just guessed and made another class for PanelBotDone and assumed the ordering columns where on

```py
# This assumes self.database is an SQLAlchemy ORM session
# and will generate an SQL with a LEFT JOIN like you described.
# Use .outerjoin() for LEFT OUTER JOIN.
query = self.database.query(
    Panel
).join(
    PanelBotDone, 
    Panel.pane_id == PanelBotDone.pane_id
).filter(
    PanelBotDone.bot_id == self.id
).order_by(
    PanelBotDone.pane_bot_uses.asc(),
    PanelBotDone.pane_goodscore.desc())

# Just one panel
panel = query.first()
# OR all the panels
panels = query.all()
```

Comment: That works great with outerjoin! And yes, I ve such PanelBotDone class. Thank you!!